# How to open modal dialog on control double click in c#

Tags: c#, controls, design-time

I am writing a control for c# (WinForms) and I have one property of Collection type.

When user select this property, button with "..." will be shown and new modal dialog will open. All this work fine, I have create:

```
public class ItemsEditor : UITypeEditor
```

In this class I have override EditValue method and open modal editor with ShowDialog. As I say this work fine.

But, I want to open this dialog when user of control double-click on it.

For this purpose I have inherit ControlDesigner:

```
public class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
```

and in this class I have inherit next method:

```
public override void DoDefaultAction()
{
    string propertyName = "Items";                      
    IServiceProvider provider = (IServiceProvider)GetService(typeof(IServiceProvider));      

    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(MyControl);

    PropertyDescriptor property = properties[propertyName];

    UITypeEditor editor = (UITypeEditor)property.GetEditor(typeof(UITypeEditor));

    editor.EditValue(provider, null);
}
```

As may be seen, I have put some random code and of course don't work.

Can somebody help me how to solve this, and how to open property on double-click.

Thank you for all help

Best regards
Bojan

Comment: Sorry, but please reword your question. This is very hard to understand.

Comment: For example: When you double-click on ListView control - Columns editor should be opened.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain about feasibility of showing the editor on double click but one of other way could be using ActionLists aka SmartTag - please see article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171829.aspx